# Search checkbox values in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ado.net

I have a dropdown list with checkbox in the page and when I select multiple options and search its not returning all the selected values in the grid. It returns only one selected value. Here is the code I use it for search. Any suggestions or change in the code. I have binded one gridview column to that checkbox. Checkbox is present outside the gridview. Any suggestions or change in the code?

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblGroup" Style="vertical-align: baseline" runat="server" CssClass="chkbox">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Below is the code on button search I am trying to fetch the checkbox values

```
  protected void btnSearchGroup_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from AppInvent_Test where Designation= '" + cblGroup.SelectedValue + "'", con);
            SqlDataAdapter Adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            Adpt.Fill(dt);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK as mentioned by Sudhakar, Try this

```
    protected void btnSearchGroup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string selectedValues = string.Empty;

                foreach (ListItem item in cblGroup.Items)
                {
                    if (item.Selected)
                        selectedValues += "'" + item.Value + "',";
                }

                if (selectedValues != string.Empty)
                    selectedValues = selectedValues.Remove(selectedValues.Length - 1);//To remove the last comma;


                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from AppInvent_Test where Designation in (" + selectedValues + ")", con);
                SqlDataAdapter Adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                Adpt.Fill(dt);
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();

            }
```

Comment: Everything is perfect but i think you need to add single quote for each selected item :) -> selectedValues += "'"+item.Value+"',"; and you can remove single quote here=> where Designation in (" + selectedValues + ")"

Comment: Akbar Ali deserve's this, he made the working solution for you.my humble Request to you is "Accept it as Answer"

Comment: Sorry Guys. I am new this forum and getting used to this:) Thanks Akbar and sudhakar.